# Multiple Frames, Multiple Buttons and Labels with changing image, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm designing a GUI with `Tkinter`. It has many frames(pages) that by pressing a button in one frame, that frame is destroyed and next frame is displayed. Each of the buttons has variable images, so I need a function that rotates the button image of each page being displayed.

I wrote the following code, the Address of the photos changes (`self.Address` in (`def counter`) of `Pagestart` class) but I think `button.config` cannot update images of button!!!Why???

(For Explain: `countercounter` function in `showframe` function of main class is responsible for updating of counter function in `pagestart`.)

the output of this code display a frame with one button that its image is constant and it can't update.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import os
import subprocess as sp
import signal

global counter0, counter1
counter0=0
counter1=0


class Project(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)      
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.configure(background="#000000")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container=container
        self.frames = {}
        for F in ( Pagestart, PageOne):   
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")             
        self.show_frame(Pagestart)
       

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.sw = 1000
        self.sh = 1800
        self.cont=cont

        for frame in self.frames.values():
          frame.grid_remove()
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.configure(background="#000000")      
        frame.grid()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.sw,self.sh,0,0))

            
        A=Pagestart(parent=self.container, controller=self)
        self.Pagestart=Pagestart
        B=A.button
        
        def countercounter(B):        
            def count1():
              global counter0, counter1
              A.counter()
              if (self.cont==Pagestart):
                  B.after(100,count1)
            count1()
        countercounter(B)
                  
        
    def twoside(self, inputaddress, startframe, stopframe):
        self.input = inputaddress
        self.startframe = startframe
        self.stopframe = stopframe       
        global counter0, counter1
        def count():  
            global counter0, counter1
            if (counter1==1):
                counter0 -=1
            if (counter1==0):
                counter0 += 1
            self.Address=('%s%s' % (str(self.input),str(counter0))+".jpg")
            if (counter0==self.stopframe):
                counter1=1
            if (counter0==self.startframe):
                counter1=0
        count()
           
    def sendAddress(self):
        return self.Address  
           
           
class Pagestart(tk.Frame):
        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller   
        self.ButtonStyle = ttk.Style()
        self.ButtonStyle.configure("Tabedstart.TButton", background="#000000", borderwidth=0)
        self.ButtonStyle.map("Tabedstart.TButton", background=[('selected', "#000000")])
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, style="Tabedstart.TButton", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        self.button.pack(pady=320)     
        self.counter()      
        
    def counter(self):
      
        self.inputaddress = "/home/pi/Documents/Reference0/"
        self.controller.twoside(self.inputaddress, 0, 138)
        self.Address = self.controller.sendAddress()
        self.photo = Image.open(self.Address)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo)       
        self.button.image=self.photo
        self.button.config(image=self.photo)
        
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller   
        self.ButtonStyle = ttk.Style()
        self.ButtonStyle.configure("Tabedstart.TButton", background="#000000", borderwidth=0)
        self.ButtonStyle.map("Tabedstart.TButton", background=[('selected', "#000000")])
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, style="Tabedstart.TButton", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Pagestart))
        self.button.pack(pady=320)     
        self.counter()      
        
    def counter(self):
      
        self.inputaddress = "/home/pi/Documents/Reference1/"
        self.controller.twoside(self.inputaddress, 0, 138)
        self.Address = self.controller.sendAddress()
        self.photo = Image.open(self.Address)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo)       
        self.button.image=self.photo
        self.button.config(image=self.photo)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Project()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: all varaibles created outside functions are global so they don't need `global`. We use `global` inside function to infor function that it has to assign value to external/global variable instead of creating local variable.

Comment: you don't destroy frame but you only hide it using `grid_forget()`/`grid_remove()`. And creating again `Pagestart` is not good idea because you already have old instance of `Pagestart` which is displayed instead of new instance - and you probably change image in new instance which is not displayed. You see old button in old instance of `Pagestart` which is displayed. You should change image in old instance of `Pagestart` which you get with `frame = self.frames[cont]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't destroy frame but you only hide it using `grid_forget()`/`grid_remove()`.

Don't create new instance of `Pagestart` because you already have old instance of `Pagestart` which is displayed with

```
frame = self.frames[cont]
frame.grid()
```

and you should change image in this instance using ie.

```
frame.counter()
```

---

Working code:

I use `self.counter` and `self.animation_direction` instead of global variables `counter0`, `counter1`.

I don't use nested functions because it is less readable.

I use `change_image()` to change image every 100ms

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Project(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)      
        
        self.counter = 1
        self.animation_direction = 1  # it will add `+1` to self.counter

        self.sw = 1000
        self.sh = 1800
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.configure(background="#000000")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.container = container
        
        self.frames = {}
        
        for F in ( PageStart, PageOne):   
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            
        self.show_frame(PageStart)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.cont = cont

        for frame in self.frames.values():
            frame.grid_remove()
          
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.configure(background="#000000")      
        frame.grid()
        frame.winfo_toplevel().geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.sw,self.sh,0,0))
        
        #frame.counter()

        self.change_image()
        
    def twoside(self, inputaddress, startframe, stopframe):
        self.input = inputaddress
        self.startframe = startframe
        self.stopframe = stopframe       
        
        self.counter += self.animation_direction

        self.address = '%s%s.jpg' % (self.input, self.counter)
        
        if self.counter == self.stopframe:
            self.animation_direction = -self.animation_direction
        if self.counter == self.startframe:
            self.animation_direction = -self.animation_direction
           
    def get_address(self):
        return self.address  
           
    def change_image(self):
        if self.cont == PageStart:
            self.frames[self.cont].counter()
            self.after(100, self.change_image)
        
           
class PageStart(tk.Frame):  # PEP8: UpperCaseNames for classes
        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.ButtonStyle = ttk.Style()
        self.ButtonStyle.configure("Tabedstart.TButton", background="#000000", borderwidth=0)
        self.ButtonStyle.map("Tabedstart.TButton", background=[('selected', "#000000")])
        
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, style="Tabedstart.TButton", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        self.button.pack(pady=320)     
        
        self.counter()      
        
    def counter(self):
      
        self.inputaddress = "/home/pi/Documents/Reference0/"
        self.controller.twoside(self.inputaddress, 0, 138)
        
        self.address = self.controller.get_address()  # PEP8: lower_case_names for functions/methods and variables
        self.photo = Image.open(self.address)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo)
        
        self.button.image = self.photo
        self.button.config(image=self.photo)
        

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
        
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.ButtonStyle = ttk.Style()
        self.ButtonStyle.configure("Tabedstart.TButton", background="#000000", borderwidth=0)
        self.ButtonStyle.map("Tabedstart.TButton", background=[('selected', "#000000")])
        
        self.button = ttk.Button(self, style="Tabedstart.TButton", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageStart))
        self.button.pack(pady=320)
        
        self.counter()      
        
    def counter(self):
      
        self.inputaddress = "/home/pi/Documents/Reference1/"
        self.controller.twoside(self.inputaddress, 0, 138)
        
        self.address = self.controller.get_address()
        self.photo = Image.open(self.address)
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.photo)
        
        self.button.image = self.photo
        self.button.config(image=self.photo)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Project()
    app.mainloop()
```